# When publishing commands in CQRS what method should I use

Tags: design-patterns, esb, cqrs, publish-subscribe

I'm probably going to be using NService bus, I understand that the dispatcher of events is going to publish the events to the subscribers but i'm wondering if it's correct to publish the commands in the 1st instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing and a pub/sub workflow makes sense for events however Commands are meant to have a single processor and therefore should be 'sent' not published. NServiceBus supports this concept in addition to pub/sub.

Note also that in a CQRS architecture queries are not commands and therefore not best suited for use with NServiceBus.